# angular-responsive-carousel installation issue - IvyCarouselModule

Tags: angular, module, carousel

I am trying to install `npm i angular-responsive-carousel`, but I am getting following error

```
npm ERR! While resolving: agp.v2.ui@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@13.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~13.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^11.2.14" from angular-responsive-carousel@2.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/angular-responsive-carousel
npm ERR!   angular-responsive-carousel@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Comment: This package is not compatible with angular version 13.1.3. So you are not allowed to installed.

Answer (score 1):

There's no version compatible with angular 13 just yet.

However, I had the same problem with angular 12 and decided to share the fix too:
use the version 2.1.0 of the angular carousel package like this
`npm i angular-responsive-carousel@2.1.0`.

Hope this helps somebody.

Reference: https://github.com/ivylaboratory/angular-carousel/issues/114#issuecomment-995196654

Answer (score 1):

install angular-responsive-carousel2:

```
npm install angular-responsive-carousel2
```

[link of npm project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-responsive-carousel2)

[link of github project](https://github.com/mojtabanpe/angular-carousel)

[link of demo](https://www.angularcarousel.top/)

Answer (score 1):

You can check my fork version: 
https://github.com/PikusSpbSandbox/carousel-angular or 
`npm i carousel-angular`
It's upgraded to compatible with Angular 14+ with a few changes and bugfixes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I fixed it with legacy-peer-deps it will allow you to ignore old dependencies for this package.
here is the code

npm i angular-responsive-carousel  --legacy-peer-deps